# $_FILE is empty when the size file is bigger, Codeigniter

Tags: php, codeigniter, upload

When I upload a Image (for example, Size 10MB), return a error "No File Selected". I make log points, but the array `$_FILE` is empty, If I try with a image with Size 5MB It's works and return a message error about the Size of image.

I do this with Ajax, and in the POST the file exist.

The problem only happens in the server (In localhost works fine)

Is problem of PHP memory?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try change `upload_max_filesize` in php.ini.

Comment: Also `post_max_size`

Comment: I will try the change post_max_size, is 8M.

Thanks!